# How to programatically create PDFmake docDefinition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf-generation, pdfmake

I am trying to create PDF's by dynamically creating the `docDefinition` from my scope data.

My data is constantly changing so dynamic creation is essential.

Below is what I have done so far, however I am not able to get my images to show in the docDefinition object / array.

```
var getExerciseImages = function(exerciseImages) {

    var imageColumns = [];
    var imageObject = {};

    for (var i = exerciseImages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        var url = 'http://files.s3.amazonaws.com/medium/' + exerciseImages[i] + '.jpg'

        convertImgToBase64URL(url).then(function(result) {
            imageObject = {
                image: result,
                fit: [200, 200]
            };

            imageColumns.push(imageObject);
        })
    };

    return imageColumns;
};

var createPdf = function(programme) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var exerciseContainer = [];
    var columns = [];

    for (var i = programme.exercises.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        exerciseContainer.push({
            text: programme.exercises[i].exerciseName.toString(),
            columns: getExerciseImages(programme.exercises[i].images)
        });

    };

    var docDefinition = {
        content: exerciseContainer

    }

    deferred.resolve(docDefinition);

    return deferred.promise;
};


function convertImgToBase64URL(url, callback, outputFormat) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
            dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        // callback(dataURL);
        deferred.resolve(dataURL);
        canvas = null;
    };
    img.src = url;

    return deferred.promise;
};


$scope.downloadPdf = function(programme) {

    createPdf(programme).then(function(docDefinition) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(docDefinition));
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
    })

};
```

The data coming in is structured like this:

```
{
    "title": "Core Stability 1",
    "id": "xt9E59f2tX",
    "exercises": [
        {
            "exerciseDescription": "Sit on a Gym Ball with thighs parallel to the floor. As you remain relaxed, gently raise the chest and ribs to straighten the spine. Maintain while raising one leg up and down followed by an arm",
            "exerciseName": "Neutral Spine on Gym ball - Single Arm or Leg lifts ",
            "images": [
                23,
                24,
                25,
                26
            ],
            "$$hashKey": "object:8"
        },
        {
            "exerciseDescription": "Sit on a Gym Ball with thighs parallel to the floor. As you remain relaxed, gently raise the chest and ribs to straighten the spine. ",
            "exerciseName": "Neutral Spine on Gym Ball ",
            "images": [
                2,
                3,
                4,
                5
            ],
            "reps": "1 Min",
            "sets": "3",
            "$$hashKey": "object:9"
        },
        {
            "exerciseDescription": "Sit on a Gym Ball with thighs parallel to the floor. Gently raise the chest and ribs to straighten the spine. Walk the feet forwards and lean backwards allowing the spine and shoulders to rest on the ball",
            "exerciseName": "Bridge on Gym Ball - Roll Down ",
            "images": [
                15,
                16,
                17
            ],
            "$$hashKey": "object:10"
        },
        {
            "exerciseDescription": "Assume the bridge position with neck and shoulders resting on the gym ball. Raise both arms pointing upwards. Move one arm above the head followed by the other",
            "exerciseName": "Bridge on Gym Ball - Arm Movements ",
            "images": [
                18,
                19,
                20,
                21,
                22
            ],
            "reps": "12",
            "sets": "3",
            "$$hashKey": "object:11"
        }
    ],
    "prescribedDate": "2015-04-09T16:23:57.020Z",
    "$$hashKey": "object:6"
}
```

This is how far I have got with the `docDefinition` :

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "text": "Half Squat ",
            "columns": []
        },
        {
            "text": "Wall Press Up",
            "columns": []
        },
        {
            "text": "Superman - Arm and Leg Lift",
            "columns": []
        },
        {
            "text": "Prone Cobra - Double Arm Shoulder Press ",
            "columns": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First load all the images into an array.Then create the dataURLs using canvas and load the dataURLs into a second array. Then pass the dataURL array to createPdf

```
    createDataURLs = function (imgs,dataURLs){
         var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
             ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
         for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
            var img=imgs[i];
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
            dataURLs[img.index] = canvas.toDataURL(img.format);    
        }

        createPdf(dataURLs);
    }

    loadAllImages = function (imageURLs, callback){
        var imgs = [];
        var dataURLs = [];
        var imagesOK=0;
        for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.format=imageURLs[i].format;
            imgs.push(img);
            dataURLs.push('');
            img.index=imgs.length-1;
            img.onload = function(){ 
                imagesOK++; 
                if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                    callback(imgs,dataURLs);
                }
            };
            img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
            img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
            img.src = imageURLs[i].url;
        }   
    }

    buildImageURLs = function(studentData){
        var imageURLs = [];
        for (var i = exerciseImages.length - 1; i ++) {

            imageURLs.push({url:'http://files.s3.amazonaws.com/medium/' + exerciseImages[i] + '.jpg',format:'image/jpeg'})
        }
        loadAllImages(imageURLs, createDataURLs);
    }
```